# Moving elements in an array SIGABRT error

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

A little background to my program: it uses a linked list to create a priority queue. Data is inserted into the *queue[25] array every time the user inputs a priority (using cin and while loop).

My problem is that after enqueueing all the data, and typing in -1 to quit, the program prints out the array (correctly) and then throws me a SIGABRT error.

The problem lies within my enqueue function:

```
void enqueue(Node *queuef[25], int priority, Node *temp)
{
    if (queuef[priority] == NULL) {
        queuef[priority] = temp;
    } else {
        int pos = 25;
        for (int i = 25; i > priority; i--)
        {
            if (queuef[priority+1] == 0)
            {
                queuef[priority+1] = temp;
                break;
            } else {
                queuef[i] = queuef[i-1];
                pos--;
            }
        }
        queuef[pos] = temp;

    }
    cout << queuef;
}
```

More specifically, the problem is in this line

```
queuef[i] = queuef[i-1];
```

When I comment out this line, the program doesn't give me the error. I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Comment: make sure the indexes you use to access queuef are valid. They must be greater or equal to 0 and less then 25. Debug your code to see the values of indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably accessing outside the bounds of the `queuef` array.  If it is 25 elements as is claimed in the parameter declaration, the first time thru the `i` loop you'll write to `queuef[25]` which is past the end of the array resulting in Undefined Behavior and your crash.